# Electron desktopCapturer for MacOS

Tags: macos, electron, core-audio, audio-streaming

I need to stream audio in my electron app from the macOS, however, I have hit the following limitation. This is from the electron documentation:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer

> **Caveats**​
>
> `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` does not work on macOS for audio
> capture due to a fundamental limitation whereby apps that want to
> access the system's audio require a signed kernel extension. Chromium,
> and by extension Electron, does not provide this.

It is possible to circumvent this limitation by capturing system audio with another macOS app like Soundflower and passing it through a virtual audio input device. This virtual device can then be queried with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.

I do not want to use another macOS app like sunflower. Is there any easy way that I can update the kernel in the app to stream it? Similar to Discord? Can I easily build an SDK to do this?

Comment: That documentation is out of date - there have been non-kernel alternatives for years now, including AudioServerPlugins and more recently AudioDriverKit System Extensions. Of the AudioServerPlugin variety, I can recommend both BackgroundMusic and Blackhole.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Will this allow me to directly stream the macOS audio from my app? Any idea how I integrate it?